# fmt::formatter specialization not understood

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I am using an opt-in method for enabling printing to the console via std::cout and fmt::print of custom classes. To do so I create a `std::string to_string(const T& value)` function that is left undefined in the general case. Specializing classes are supposed to:

1. specialize `to_string(const MyType& t)`
2. specialize `struct printable< MyType >: public std::true_type{}`

This will in turn activate `std::ostream` and  `fmt::formatter` which specialize automatically for every `printable` type. A complete example is this:

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace common {

template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& value);

template <typename T>
struct printable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool printable_v = printable<T>::value;

}  // namespace common

template <typename T>
    requires(common::printable_v<T>)
auto& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& value) {
    return os << common::to_string(value);
}

template <class T>
    requires(common::printable_v<T>)
struct fmt::formatter<T> : public fmt::ostream_formatter {};

struct MyClass {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    auto begin() { return v.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return v.begin(); }
    auto end() { return v.end(); }
    auto end() const { return v.end(); }
};

namespace common {
inline std::string to_string(const MyClass& c) {
    return fmt::format("{}", c.v);
}

template <>
struct printable<MyClass> : std::true_type {};
}  // namespace common

int main() {
    // this works:
    // std::cout << common::to_string(MyClass{});
    // this doesn't:
    fmt::format("{}", MyClass{});
}
```

However, for `fmt` v10.1.1 this brings up somewhat cryptic error messages (clang-17):

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/type_traits:1048:21: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'std::__is_complete_or_unbounded(std::__type_identity<fmt::formatter<MyClass, char, void>>{})': template argument must be a complete class or an unbounded array
 1048 |       static_assert(std::__is_complete_or_unbounded(__type_identity<_Tp>{}),
```

and

```
<source>:55:17: error: call to consteval function 'fmt::basic_format_string<char, MyClass>::basic_format_string<char[3], 0>' is not a constant expression
   55 |     fmt::format("{}", MyClass{});
```

The example can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1j1Eb5Y8M) on godbolt.

Why isn't my formatter method accepted and how can I make fmt understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyClass` is a range (it has `begin()` and `end()` which return iterators). `fmt` has a default formatter for all ranges, which conflicts with the formatter you're trying to add. Neither is more specialized than the other, so it's ambiguous.

If you [disable the range formatter](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/89860eb9013a345608c8144b1aad5f12b0682d7e/include/fmt/ranges.h#L549-L553), then only yours will be used:

```cpp
template <typename Char>
struct fmt::range_format_kind<MyClass, Char>
    : std::integral_constant<fmt::range_format, fmt::range_format::disabled>
{ };
```

Once you do that, though, your actual customization for `to_string` isn't quite right (you'll get an undefined reference to `common::to_string<MyClass>` since your function won't be considered), but that's a separate problem.

Comment: `concept printable=requires(ostream&s, T t){ {to_string(t)->same_as<ostream&>;}`?

Comment: This does fix the problem, but it feels wrong needing to intervene in the details of fmt. I would have expected there to be a public API that allows to fine-tune this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MichaelA It's intended to be public - the equivalent one in [the standard library](https://eel.is/c++draft/format.range.fmtkind) is public.

Comment: @MichaelA Oh oops, I put the wrong one - there is an _actually_ public one that you're actually supposed to use.

Comment: @Barry thanks, that makes more sense to me now! Using a lib's ::detail is something I tend to avoid :)